# Is it possible to run graphical applications such as Firefox without installing a full desktop environment in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line, gui, arch-linux

I have been an Ubuntu user for 2 years and am contemplating moving to Arch. I love their philosophy, [The Arch Way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/The_Arch_Way), and I admire their tenacity to bare the system to the user. I think if I am ever going to tame my Linux Box and be a [superuser](http://superuser.com), it is the only way. I am willing to go all the way to get a real Arch experience, compiling packages from source  to install and editing configuration files to change system settings. However, there are applications that are a part of my daily workflow and I don't know if they will run without a gui/desktop environment. Crucial among them is Firefox.

It would be great if I could use one or two graphical applications without having to install a desktop environment. Is this possible on Linux?

Comment: Note that there *are* text-only web browsers available (e.g., lynx) which don't require a desktop environment or any of the X libraries.  Useful if you only need web-browsing capability, rather than *graphical* web-browsing capability.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "desktop environment"? Do you mean large ones like KDE or Gnome, or just an X server and window manager?

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/50599/how-do-you-run-a-gui-application-without-gui-gui-application-as-daemon-on-headl

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, Firefox REQUIRES X server. What you would need is to  install Firefox with the help of the package management - it should install the bare minimum of the packages, including the X server. Then, you just need to run the X server without the desktop environnment. Basically something like:

```
$ X
```

Then you just start Firefox in this X server:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 firefox
```

You can switch from the X server and the framebuffer by using CTRL+ALT+F1 and CTRL+ALT+F7.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is spot on. I am going to try it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Without a graphical environment, you will need to use a text-based browser such as elinks/lynx, and they are really [not very pretty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Elinks0.11.1_screenshot.png).

You can just run X by itself, and then spawn graphical utilities from the command line specifying "server :0" manually, however this is a real bother.

If you are into minimalism, you could try a lightweight windows-manager. See [Arch-wiki Window Manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_Manager) for the whole list. I don't use Arch, but some people recommend [Fluxbox](http://www.fluxbox.org/). You will need to experiment with them to find the one you like.

Comment: A window manager will be very tempting to go back to using graphical applications. I want to keep my setup as simple as possible, mainly because I intend to use my computer mostly for programming and surfing. I knew about lynx, and did try it on Ubuntu. You are right, it's not pretty at all.

Comment: Programming without graphical productivity applications such as IDE is like cutting your arm off before going to war. Or you have a computer with extremely little RAM.

Comment: vim or emacs are enough for many programmers and both work well without X

Comment: @harrymc What are your sources? What about not having graphical productivity applications is so harmful? Do you think IDEs are so much better than console-based text editors?

Comment: @Kelmikra: This is too vast a subject for discussing here.

Comment: @harrymc I see. What about just pointing to some sources that discuss this?

Comment: @Kelmikra: One can find sources in every direction, but experience speaks louder than any source.

Comment: @harrymc My experience suggests that using text editors in consoles is just as productive, if not more, than using IDEs. A cursory online searched turned up nothing relevant on the topic.

Comment: @Kelmikra: We may differ on experience. Large projects may be very hard to work on file-by-file, for example when refactoring. An IDE can automate many development and maintenance functions.

Comment: @harrymc That sounds right. My understanding is that text editors are useful for working on individual files, while IDEs are good for integrating files in large projects.

Comment: @Kelmikra: IDEs can also have helpful side-panels and do auto-complete and have actions such as "go to definition" or "show all uses of" etc. etc.

Comment: @harrymc I suppose there is little reason for us to continue discussing this, given that it has been discussed elsewhere (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206755/ide-vs-text-editor).